# URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier returns nil even if configured correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, icloud

I am having the problem, that URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier is returning nil in some cases even if the user has set up everything correctly in the settings. My code:

```
dispatch_async(someQueue, ^{

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil]) {
        ErrLog(@"iCloud container not available.");
        return;
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [...]
    });

});
```

Does anybody came across the same problem? I am setting nil as the container identifier which should work according to the Apple docs, but I am not so convinced anymore about that. Also this code works fine for the majority of users, but somehow not for everybody.

Comment: One user just reported that it works after installing iOS 5.1 beta 2.

Comment: Having the same problem, that method always returns nil

Comment: I am now setting the correct container identifier. This has no effect. Still having this problem with some users.

Comment: iCloud Drive on device need to be turned on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898771/why-ubiquityidentitytoken-returns-nil/25900686#25900686

Comment: if you're using old ubiquity containers, iCloud drive does not need to be on, just Documents & Settings (see ios8 commentary below)

Answer (score 8):

Check that you have enabled iCloud containers in your entitlement. The containers are not added by default when you enable entitlements. Click the "+" sign in Target/Summary/Entitlements to add your appId.

Comment: Even though xCode says that it has added the iCloud entitlement to my entitlements file, it really didn't and I had to add it manually.  When I added it manually, the `URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier` works and returns a non-nil URL, but Xcode complains in the Capabilities tab is offers to fix the "problem".  If you ask it to fix the problem, it'll delete the entry that you've just added from the entitlement.  It looks like a buf.  I'm using Xcode 6 beta 5.

Answer (score 8):

iPad mini with iOS7. I just have experienced that URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier suddenly started to return nil. I tried restarting the device, but it didn't help.

Inside the Settings app, under the 'iCloud' menu. I noticed that 'Documents & Data' was set to  Off.

Solution was to change 'Documents & Data' to 'On'.

Answer (score 7):

If anyone is having the same problem using the iOS8 Betas, there seems to be a bug with the way the Entitlements are generated in Xcode 6. I was banging my head against this for days until coming across this post in the Apple Developer Forums: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/229509?

Essentially, Xcode generates a key named `com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers` when it should be `com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers` (**ubiquity**, not **icloud**). It may also have the value set as `iCloud.$(CFBundleIdentifier)` when it should be `$(TeamIdentifierPrefix).$(CFBundleIdentifier)`.

Of course this may get fixed in the next Beta but for anyone as confused as me I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes this is different in Xcode 5 to 6. but it does actually work with the Xcode 6 changes (at least, on a device it does)

I think the difference is to support CloudKit, there is a switch on the provisioning portal which selects between the Xcode 5 and Xcode 6 methods.

Comment: I had to switch on default containers, compile it (which added the icloud keys to entitlements), then switch back to custom containers and add $(TeamIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier) <- notice no dot between them. then it picked up my old ubiquity container files in the app

Comment: Note - it still says "fix issue" in xcode 6, but everything is working fine...i just love apple icloud so much. i guess older code that works fine using ubiquity is not in their test suites

Comment: I did everything that is mentioned in this answer and now I can generate an archive, but when I try to run it on the device I get the `The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016)` error.  The app also runs in the simulator and on the simulator the app gets access to the old iCloud data (corresponding to the container that starts with the TeamID).  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

I'd look at your entitlement.plist on one app I needed to change $(TEAMID) to profile id 
the  numbers and letter before the dns in the profile - here is some code that will work with UIManagedDocument

```
/// test iCloud Access
- (void)initializeiCloudAccess {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]
             URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil] != nil)
            NSLog(@"iCloud is available\n");
        else
            NSLog(@"This Application requires iCloud, but it is not available.\n");
    });
}

- (NSURL *)iCloudURL
{

    return [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
}

- (NSURL *)iCloudDocumentsURL
{

    return [[self iCloudURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
}

- (NSURL *)iCloudCoreDataLogFilesURL
{

    return [[self iCloudURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"CoreDataLogs"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier alway return nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769542/urlforubiquitycontaineridentifier-alway-return-nil)

```
NSURL *ubiquityURL = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil]; if (ubiquityURL == nil)
```

- app build by xcode4.5
- app is enable icloud
- ios is loginned icloud account

ubiquityURL is normal in debug, but ubiquityURL is always nil after distribution to appstore.

Comment: i fill it.
please don't use " xcode4.5 gm or xocde4.5 + icloud sdk" to sumbit app .
i use xocde4.5.1 + icloud sdk, then is ok now
This issue has been verified as resolved and can be closed.

Comment: i fill it.
please don't use " xcode4.5 gm or xocde4.5 + icloud sdk" to sumbit app .
i use xocde4.5.1 + icloud sdk, then is ok now
This issue has been verified as resolved and can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Today I experienced this problem again.

This time it was because I had an invalid provisioning profile.

[image: Invalid provisioning profile]

On the developer site, I had to generate a new provisioning profile. Afterward reload the provisioning profiles within Xcode5. Now `URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier` again returns valid urls.

Answer (score 0):

If you still having issue o make sure you are running on a device as simulator wont always return a valid value .
I tried you code on my app and Im not getting nil

Answer (score 0):

Enable "iCloud Drive" in the iPhone's Settings