# URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier alway return nil

Tags: ios, core-data, release, icloud

`URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:` always returns `nil`

```
NSURL *ubiquityURL = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
if (ubiquityURL == nil)
```

1. app build by **xcode 4.5**
2. app is enabled **iCloud**
3. **IOS** is logged in into **iCloud** account

`ubiquityURL` is normal in debug, but `ubiquityURL` is always `nil` after distribution to app store.

Comment: i fill it.
please don't use " xcode4.5 gm or xocde4.5 + icloud sdk" to sumbit app .
i use xocde4.5.1 + icloud sdk, then is ok now
This issue has been verified as resolved and can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your release configuration has the wrong entitlements. What is your com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers values in your .entitlements plist?