# NSFileManager ubiquityIdentityToken returns nil unexpectedly?

Tags: ios, ipad, icloud, nsfilemanager

I am using this iCloud library within my application: https://github.com/iRareMedia/iCloudDocumentSync

On my iPhone running iOS 8, I run the app and ubiquityIdentityToken returns a value and everything works fine. However on my iPad running iOS 7.0.4, it returns nil.

I ensured a few things on the iPad:

1. The iPad is connected to wifi and can connect to the internet fine
2. iCloud is in fact set up on the iPad. I can see this because it says so in Settings and iCloud tabs are working in Safari.
3. The documents and data option is in fact enabled
4. Xcode set up iCloud automatically via the capabilities iCloud tab and it works on my iPhone with the same set up.

Is there any reason why this could be happening? It seems hard to believe that it can work on one device and not the next. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know iOS 8 is still under NDA so this answer can't be as specific here as I would like it to be but I'll just say the following. This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24584019/394736 points to this link: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/229509 and that fixed it for me on both iOS 7 and iOS 8 devices!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your problem, but Apple does mention in [What's New in iOS 8](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html) that a user's iCloud data in iOS 8 is incompatible with iOS 7:

"The iCloud infrastructure is more robust and reliable when documents and data are transferred between user devices and the server. When a user installs iOS 8 and logs into the device with an iCloud account, the iCloud server performs a one-time migration of the documents and data in that user’s account. This migration involves copying the documents and data to a new version of the app’s container directory. This new container is accessible only to devices running iOS 8 or OS X v10.10. Devices running older operating systems will continue to have access to the original container, but changes made in that container will not appear in the new container and vice versa."

Edit:

To see if this is your problem, you should test on two iOS 8 devices and compare to two iOS 7 devices. If you are still running into the same issue on the same versions of iOS there is something else going on as well.

Comment: Good thing to bring up but it actually was an entitlements issue which I explained in my own answer above. :)