# Why ubiquityIdentityToken returns nil?

Tags: ios, icloud, icloud-api

`NSFileManager.defaultManager().ubiquityIdentityToken` on some device in some case returns nil, even I set up `iCloud Documents` in Capabilities and I am logged in to iCloud on device. How reliable operation of the `ubiquityIdentityToken` do you met? Am I doing something wrong?

On iPhone it returns correctly with a real token, but on iPad it returns with nil, even if I am logged in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get token, you need additionaly to turn on `iCloud Drive` on device. If it is off `ubiquityIdentityToken` will return nil.

[image]

Comment: and if don't want to turn on iCloud drive?!?! is it mandatory?

Comment: I am not sure it is mandatory, but I spent googling a lot and this was what helped