# Default container on iCloud not working for key-value storage

Tags: xcode6, icloud, nsfilemanager, key-value-store

Somewhere in the change from Xcode 5 to Xcode 6, and the changes online to the iCloud management system, I lost the ability to store data into key-value storage in iCloud. More specifically, now, both:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
```

and

```
[NSFileManager defaultManager].ubiquityIdentityToken
```

now both return nil. Previously (at least) URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier returned non-nil.

I tried the answers given here: [Why ubiquityIdentityToken returns nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898771/why-ubiquityidentitytoken-returns-nil?rq=1) and here https://devforums.apple.com/thread/229509 but no joy.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a fix to this. I first tried a sample project with Xcode 6, targeting iOS6 (I need to maintain iOS6 compatibility). I had these settings under Capabilities:

[image]

It seems like the default container setting is not working with just key-value storage. That is, with settings as above, ubiquityIdentityToken returns nil.

I next tried checking the CloudKit box, and then specifying a custom container. That might have worked except for my iOS6 compatibility issue. CloudKit doesn't work on iOS6.

I then tried checking the iCloud Documents box (hacking my way to greatness? ;)):

[image]

This causes ubiquityIdentityToken to return non-nil! And when I make this change in my actual application, as opposed to this test application, my key-value storage works again! (It does also work on iOS8.1).

The relevant parts of my entitlement file are now:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers</key>
<array>
    <string>iCloud.$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
</array>
<key>com.apple.developer.icloud-services</key>
<array>
    <string>CloudDocuments</string>
</array>
<key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers</key>
<array>
    <string>iCloud.$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
</array>
<key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
<string>$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
```