# How to enable iCloud for Core Data?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, icloud

This is the first time I'm trying to make this work. I'm following the [iCloud Programming Guide for Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/UsingCoreDataWithiCloudPG/Introduction/Introduction.html), the "Using the SQLite Store with iCloud" section, and in `AppDelegate` I have:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
   // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it.
   if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
       return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
   }

   // Create the coordinator and store

   _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
   NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyApp.sqlite"];
   NSError *error = nil;
   NSString *failureReason = @"There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.";

   // To enable iCloud
   NSDictionary *storeOptions = @{NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey: @"MyAppCloudStore"};

   if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:storeOptions error:&error]) {
       // Report any error we got.
       NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
       dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = @"Failed to initialize the application's saved data";
       dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason;
       dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error;
       error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN" code:9999 userInfo:dict];
       // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
       // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
       NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
       abort();
   }

   return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Previously, I enabled iCloud services for this App ID, create the corresponding provisioning, and turn on the iCloud services in Xcode's capabilities (iCloud Documents and default container).

According to the `iCloud Programming Guide for Core Data`, at this point:

> Test: Run the app on a device. If Core Data successfully created and configured an iCloud-enabled persistent store, the framework logs a message containing “Using local storage: 1,” and, later, another message containing “Using local storage: 0”.

I run the app on an iPhone, and `persistentStoreCoordinator` is retrieved, but I see nothing in Xcode's debug area.

What am I missing?

Thanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] ubiquityIdentityToken]` was returning `nil`, and it was because I had my device not updated to `iCloud Drive`.

I found the response in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898771/why-ubiquityidentitytoken-returns-nil).